# CSS clear both IE bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When I use `clear:both` code in CSS div tag it doesn't show correctly on IE.

this is firefox:
[image]

this is IE 6
[image]

You can see in firefox it's show correctly, But **IE 6** it doesn't show correctly. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Please check this.

http://jsfiddle.net/sasindu555/xmKAT/

Comment: You should post the rest of your code, or a link so we can troubleshoot with the rest of the document in context. - you could also try using jsfiddle.net for this....

Comment: Which version of IE is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forget to mention that. IE 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `font-size: 0;` to `#h-spacer`

IE6 can't make a `1px` high `div` it defaults to 16px(or default) height to leave room for text line-height

Comment: thank you very much. I just added `font-size: 0;`. My problem solved.

Comment: You're Welcome - just one of 6's little foibles ;)

Comment: yes. I have another issues with IE6. some divs not showing borders and background. :(

Comment: @Sassi they are usually symptoms of a hasLayout issue.. disappearing content and borders that is.. To test if it is, add `* {zoom: 1;}` to the end of your styles (don't worry it might throw some things out of alignment, but) - does it bring back your borders and backgrounds?.. if so you then need to get picky as to where to apply that fix, look for an ancestor div/element of the affected element that has padding/margin/border (all or either) but no width and try applying `zoom` to all of them - Good Luck!